# Cannot access a resource directory in intelliJ, while importing a project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, module

[image]I have imported my project from git, and set the Source root accordingly, as User/sharan/Chess/Chess/src, where "sharan" is my home dir. In my main class i try to access a png icon from the dir path sharan/Chess/Chess/icon/" ".png, but it does not seem to fetch the icon image. I am sure however my using of the function and the path is right, because it works fine when i used it from my other machine where i programmed this application.

I think it is because i have not configured my modules right, or not configured the icons folder. I tried marking icons directory as a Resource root but still no difference.

```
squares[CurrentBoard.board.get(i).x][CurrentBoard.board.get(i).y].setIcon(new ImageIcon(CurrentBoard.board.get(i).filename));
```

where i have defined filename as a data member for the object, that specifies the path for the png image.
e.g icons/Knight_black.png

this line^ works fine i am sure, because it worked on my other machine. But it is not fetching the image from the dir icons, however program works fine with no error.

Comment: if the file is in the project dir you should reference relatively not absolute. do you get any exceptions?

Comment: @mavriksc icons/" ".png is the relative address, i have confirmed this by copying the relative address directly off intelliJ of the file. And no, no excpetions

Comment: Can you show your project file structure?

Comment: @EugenCovaci i have added a picture, icons dir contains files like Knight_black.png etc.. but i am convinced it is not really a path problem because the path works fine on my original machine, it only had a problem when i imported this project freshly from git

Comment: Please post the `CurrentBoard.board.get(i).filename` value

Comment: @EugenCovaci it will return, icons/Knight_black.png as an example.

Comment: @EugenCovaci i have come across a solution and have answered it myself, thanks alot for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

After browsing i came across a solution in which instead of accessing files, it was recommended i used a "resources" folder in src. So after copying all my pngs to the resources folder and changing the code to:

```
.....new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(CurrentBoard.board.get(i).filename)));
```

it works perfectly..